# Запятая перед союзом "как" ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, как, союзы

*Дельфины общаются между собой как люди.*

Answer (score 2):

1) Всё зависит от текста. Здесь  нет обособления, если   речь идет о том, что дельфины общаются особенным образом,  а именно **составляют слова** из характерных звуков:  **Дельфины общаются между собой как люди** (подобно людям).

Но (для сравнения): **Дельфины общаются между собой   "словами", как люди**. В этом случае признак уже назван, а сравнительный оборот дополняет его.

Из Интернета: "Исследователи знали, что млекопитающие имеют развитую форму коммуникации. Дельфины, используя характерные щелчки и свистки, показывают, что они рады, счастливы или отделены от группы. **Но теперь учёные доказали, что дельфины изменяют частоту и объем импульсных щелчков, чтобы сформировать отдельные «слова», которые собраны в предложения**. Это практически так же, как говорят люди". [Дельфины общаются между собой подобно людям | news.sevas.com](http://news.sevas.com/crimea/delfiny_obshhayutsya_mezhdu_soboj_kak_lyudi_vyyasnili_uchenye)

2) Если бы речь шла просто о факте  общения, то предложение имело бы другое содержание, например: **Дельфины постоянно  общаются между собой, как люди.**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

А вообще говоря, сравнительный оборот – вещь непростая, **и этот пример удачен для понимания его сути**.  К примеру, (1) **сравниваются два предмета, которые совершают одно и то же действие:** Люди общаются между собой,  и дельфины общаются между собой, если коротко: Дельфины, как люди,  общаются между собой.   (2) **А теперь  мы хотим рассказать о способе общения (КАК ОНИ ОБЩАЮТСЯ)**, и оказывается, что они общаются **с помощью слов, как и люди**.  И вот теперь оборот «как люди» несет  особую информацию – о словесном общении дельфинов – и становится **необособленным обстоятельством образа действия по отношению к глаголу "общаться".**

Comment: А на основании каких правил вы такие утверждения делаете? Запятая - да, не нужна, наверное, Но при чем тут слова и звуки? Ну а Ваши примеры для сравнения - это просто что-то удивительное. Туд даже смысла такого трудно углядеть. "Общаются" как люди"  значит, что передают информации, делятся чем-то, даже эмоциями... Почему обязательно "словами"?

Comment: Вариант 1. Дельфины, как люди, общаются между собой. Сообщается факт общения, это обособленный сравнительный оборот. Вариант 2.  Дельфины общаются  как люди (словами и предложениями). Сообщается способ общения, это необособленное обстоятельство образа действия, отвечает на вопрос как? каким образом? А правило у Розенталя:

Comment: Обороты с союзом как не выделяются запятыми:
1)      если на первый план в обороте выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (на вопрос как?); обычно такие обороты можно заменить творительным падежом существительного или наречием, например: Как град посыпалась картечь (Лермонтов) (ср.: посыпалась градом); Как дым рассеялись мечты (Лермонтов);  Перстенек как жар горит (Некрасов); В гневе он как гром загремел, как сталь засверкал;  Как зарницы в небе они запылали, как огненный дождь с неба упали;http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

Comment: Ой как много слов-то... А на вопрос не ответили. Нет таких правил. Т.е. правила есть, но к ним очень трудно привязать ваши разговоры про слова и звуки.

Comment: ** если на первый план в обороте выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (на вопрос как?)** - это да, но причем тут дельфиньи слова? Слова - это не образ действия. Это инструмент, если угодно. И ясно, что автор не это имел в виду..

Comment: На Т.п. обратите внимание – разговаривают  (как ?) словами ( а не знаками/жестами) (лат. verbalis «словесный»). Словесное общение в мире животных  - это удивительно, не правда ли?

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина в комментариях. Автор де5лает вывод о пунктуации на основании каких-то разговорах о словах и звуках(?!). Объяснения не последовало.

Answer (score 1):

Ставится, конечно. Это же сравнение, ничем не отягощённое.

[**Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК.**](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

Дельфины же на самом деле не люди, это их общение уподоблено.

*Дельфины общаются между собой, как люди.*

Answer (score -1):

Я бы здесь не ставил. Без оборота с "как" предложение на мой взгляд не закончено. 
Другими словами, тут авторский знак, в зависимости от смысла. Если важно подчеркнуть, что именно "как люди", то без запятой.